# Iceberg's FlinkSink doesn't update metadata file in streaming writes

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming, apache-iceberg

I have been trying to use Iceberg's FlinkSink to consume the data and write to sink.

I was successful in fetching the data from kinesis and I see that the data is being written into the appropriate partition. However, I don't see the `metadata.json` being updated. Without which I am not able to query the table.

The following is the code.

```
package test

import java.util.{Calendar, Properties}

import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SimpleStringSchema
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.FlinkKinesisConsumer
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.config.{AWSConfigConstants, ConsumerConfigConstants}
import org.apache.flink.table.data.{GenericRowData, RowData, StringData}
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.iceberg.catalog.TableIdentifier
import org.apache.iceberg.flink.{CatalogLoader, TableLoader}
import org.apache.iceberg.flink.TableLoader.HadoopTableLoader
import org.apache.iceberg.flink.sink.FlinkSink
import org.apache.iceberg.hadoop.HadoopCatalog
import org.apache.iceberg.types.Types
import org.apache.iceberg.{PartitionSpec, Schema}

import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

object SampleApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

    val warehouse = "file://<local folder path>"

    val catalog = new HadoopCatalog(new Configuration(), warehouse)
    val ti = TableIdentifier.of("test_table")

    if (!catalog.tableExists(ti)) {
      println("table doesnt exist. creating it.")

      val schema = new Schema(
        Types.NestedField.optional(1, "message", Types.StringType.get()),
        Types.NestedField.optional(2, "year", Types.StringType.get()),
        Types.NestedField.optional(3, "month", Types.StringType.get()),
        Types.NestedField.optional(4, "date", Types.StringType.get()),
        Types.NestedField.optional(5, "hour", Types.StringType.get())
      )

      val props = Map(
        "write.metadata.delete-after-commit.enabled" -> "true",
        "write.metadata.previous-versions-max" -> "5",
        "write.target-file-size-bytes" -> "1048576"
      )

      val partitionSpec = PartitionSpec.builderFor(schema)
        .identity("year")
        .identity("month")
        .identity("date")
        .identity("hour")
        .build();

      catalog.createTable(ti, schema, partitionSpec, props.asJava)
    } else {
      println("table exists. not creating it.")
    }


    val inputProperties = new Properties()
    inputProperties.setProperty(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_REGION, "us-east-1")
    inputProperties.setProperty(ConsumerConfigConstants.STREAM_INITIAL_POSITION, "LATEST")

    val stream: DataStream[RowData] = env
      .addSource(new FlinkKinesisConsumer[String]("test_kinesis_stream", new SimpleStringSchema(), inputProperties))
      .map(x => {
        val now = Calendar.getInstance()
        GenericRowData.of(
          StringData.fromString(x),
          StringData.fromString(now.get(Calendar.YEAR).toString),
          StringData.fromString("%02d".format(now.get(Calendar.MONTH))),
          StringData.fromString("%02d".format(now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))),
          StringData.fromString("%02d".format(now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)))
        )
      })

    FlinkSink
      .forRowData(stream.javaStream)
      .tableLoader(TableLoader.fromHadoopTable(s"$warehouse/${ti.name()}", new Configuration()))
      .build()

    env.execute("test app")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should set checkpointing:

```
env.enableCheckpointing(1000)
```